# Comparing strings not working properly vb.net

Tags: vb.net, equals, equals-operator

I'm trying to compare 2 strings (KeyCode and SerialN)
I've tried a bunch of diferente aproaches... but as you can see in my print screen neither = or Equals work.

Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
Private Function VerificaKeyCode(SerialN As String) As Boolean
        Dim snEsq As Integer
        Dim snDir As Integer
        Dim KeyCode As String
        Dim buffer As String
        Dim ind As Short

        VerificaKeyCode = False
        buffer = Space(255)
        For ind = 1 To 5
            'UPGRADE_WARNING: App property App.EXEName has a new behavior. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6BA9B8D2-2A32-4B6E-8D36-44949974A5B4"'
            GetPrivateProfileString(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, "HD" & ind, "", buffer, Len(buffer), My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ServerHD.ini")
            KeyCode = Trim(buffer)
            If KeyCode <> "" Then
                VerificaKeyCode = KeyCode.Equals(SerialN)
                VerificaKeyCode = CBool(KeyCode = SerialN)
                If VerificaKeyCode Then Exit Function
            End If
        Next ind
    End Function
```

[image]

Edit

Aparently there is an empty char in the string, I need to remove it somehow

[image]

Comment: Don't use screen shots, please post the code as, well, code here

Comment: I guess you're in the wrong line of execution. Your variable still has the value assigned by the previous statement. Execute the current line and our should be true.

Comment: = or equals should deliver the same result; but you have to make sure that both inputs are identical (it = or equals say that they are not identical is because they aren't). There are various reasons why your variables may not be identical; for example you are trimming one of them and not the other one (and in the first comparisons you are only applying ToUpper to one of the variables). Just be consistent and make sure that you apply the same modifications to all the variables. For example: .Trim().ToUpper() to all the variables involved in a string comparison sounds fine.

Comment: the current line is not true... all those lines return false

Comment: Setting the result multiple times won't change anything. Because of that you use `VerificaKeyCode = <...>` you keep setting it based on the latest check. And for functions, you should use `Return` instead. This is an example on how you can return the check of multiple variables: `Return (KeyCode = teste1 Or teste2 = teste1)`

Comment: I know, that messy code is because I made multiple tries to make it work. The thing is KeyCode and SerialN variables have the same value.. yet Equals fails... (you can see the value of the variables in the printscreen)

Comment: you may not be using `GetPrivateProfileString` the most optimal way for .NET, please add the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions in your watch window are stale as indicated by the disabled color and the presence of the Refresh/Recycle icon.  Click the icon and the expression will be re-evaluated and the result updated:

[image]

Mimicking what you have, notice the first expression is stale and wrong.  The second has been refresh/reevaluated and reports the correct result.  As soon as you execute a line of code, the watch expressions will be marked as stale/not updated.

---

A better way to return a function with NET is to use a local variable and `Return` it.  The local var allow you to easily view the result by hovering the mouse:

> [image]

A variable can go out of scope, but it can't be stale.

---

Edit 4 or 5 reveals that while the watch expressions *are* stale, so what we see in the pic neither proves nor disproves that the strings do not match, this is apparently a VB6 -> .NET refurb (notice the 102 warnings).

We cant see the declaration for `GetPrivateProfileString` but the usage is at least suboptimal.

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(appname As String,
                                        keyname As String, def As String,
                                        sbuffer As StringBuilder, 
                                        nSize As Int32,
                                        strFile As String) As Integer
End Function
```

Note that it is a Function; it returns the number of chars read into the buffer.  Rather than `Trim` which will not remove `NUL`, the return should be used (if not a stringbuilder) to get the number of characters specified.  If you use a string buffer, trim to the number of characters read:

```
Dim n As Int32 = GetPrivateProfileString(...)
KeyCode = buffer.Substring(0, n)
```

StringBuilder should do that for you:

```
Dim buffer As New StringBuilder(255)
...
Dim n As Int32 = GetPrivateProfileString(..., buffer, buffer.Capacity)
KeyCode = buffer.ToString()
```

You can still check the function return against the size of the string.

---

You could skip `GetPrivateProfileString` entirely and read the file yourself with a stream reader.  It should be faster than PInvoke, but at the least, less convoluted to use.

Comment: I have cleaned my mess and put a new print screen... Its a very weird "error". All the grey values in the print are refreshed values... but it only shows one has being "fresh" for some reason

Comment: the current image still shows the watch expressions as stale; store the result to a local var and look at **that**

Comment: I've add a watch to the variable, so that you can see it returns false. I think thats the best I can do. Maybe its related with diferent string codings?

Comment: use `Dim snChars = serialN.ToCharArray()` on both vars to see if that is true - just hold your mouse over the variable and click the `+`.  See if there are identical

Comment: With your sugestion I found there is and invisible char, I've converted it to an array of bites and found that has the value of 0 (probably the \0 to signal the end of the string) how can I clean it?

Comment: your Pinvoke is wrong - post the declaration for `GetPrivateProfileString`

Comment: 'UPGRADE_ISSUE: Declaring a parameter 'As Any' is not supported. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="FAE78A8D-8978-4FD4-8208-5B7324A8F795"'
    Public Declare Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer